# "New York City" geometry is missing in geopands

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, heatmap, geopandas

I am trying create heat map on few cities of world and found "New York City" is missing from geopands.

```
cities = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
print(cities[cities['name'] == 'New York City'])
print(cities[cities['name'] == 'London'])
Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: [name, geometry]
Index: []
       name                   geometry
187  London  POINT (-0.11867 51.50194)
```

Am I missing anything in code? How can I get "New York City" information?

Comment: List the cities and find out how it's actually called. I'd bet it's `New York` instead of `New York City`. Very few city names actually have the `City` word in their names.

Comment: `'nybb'` in the `get_path()` lists all the regions in New York City.

[Look here](https://geopandas.org/gallery/plotting_basemap_background.html?highlight=datasets)

Answer (score 2):

`naturalearth_cities` does not contain `New York City`.

A simple `list(cities['name'])` will display all the city names in the dataframe.

```
['Vatican City', 'San Marino', 'Vaduz', 'Luxembourg', 'Palikir', 'Majuro', 'Funafuti', 'Melekeok', 'Monaco', 'Tarawa', 'Moroni', 'Andorra', 'Port-of-Spain', 'Kigali', 'Mbabane', 'Juba', 'Ljubljana', 'Bratislava', 'Doha', 'Podgorica', 'Bern', 'Pristina', 'Roseau', 'Djibouti', 'Banjul', 'Skopje', 'Bridgetown', 'Bujumbura', 'Kingstown', 'Castries', 'Basseterre', 'Port Louis', "Saint George's", 'Manama', "Saint John's", 'Montevideo', 'Lome', 'Tunis', 'Abu Dhabi', 'Ashgabat', 'Lusaka', 'Harare', 'Dili', 'Port Vila', 'Tegucigalpa', 'Georgetown', 'Reykjavík', 'Port-au-Prince', 'Kampala', 'Paramaribo', 'Niamey', 'Dushanbe', 'Asuncion', 'Managua', 'Freetown', 'Islamabad', 'Kathmandu', 'Bloemfontein', 'Pretoria', 'Port Moresby', 'Honiara', 'Panama City', 'Rabat', 'Chisinau', 'Maputo', 'Mogadishu', 'Muscat', 'Colombo', 'Ulaanbaatar', 'Wellington', 'Windhoek', 'Abuja', 'Bissau', 'Amman', 'Vilnius', 'Riga', 'Bishkek', 'Maseru', 'Antananarivo', 'Quito', 'San Jose', 'San Salvador', 'Kingston', 'Ndjamena', 'Malabo', 'Asmara', 'Zagreb', 'Tallinn', 'Lilongwe', 'Guatemala', 'Libreville', 'Suva', 'Nouakchott', 'Bamako', 'Beirut', 'Tbilisi', 'Astana', 'Vientiane', 'Brazzaville', 'Conakry', 'Yamoussoukro', 'Ottawa', 'Belgrade', 'Bandar Seri Begawan', 'Sucre', 'Belmopan', 'Bangui', 'Yaounde', 'Tirana', 'Yerevan', 'Baku', 'Phnom Penh', 'La Paz', 'Cotonou', 'Sofia', 'Minsk', 'Thimphu', 'Gaborone', 'Canberra', 'Ouagadougou', 'Sarajevo', 'Naypyidaw', 'Nukualofa', 'Hargeysa', 'Victoria', 'Sao Tome', 'Apia', 'Valletta', 'Male', 'Jerusalem', 'Praia', 'Nassau', 'Nicosia', 'Hanoi', 'Ankara', 'Budapest', 'Sanaa', 'Bucharest', 'Damascus', 'Lisbon', 'Khartoum', 'Oslo', 'Warsaw', 'Pyongyang', 'Dar es Salaam', 'Dublin', 'Monrovia', 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Havana', 'Prague', 'Kuwait', 'Santo Domingo', 'Accra', 'Tripoli', 'Helsinki', 'København', 'Abidjan', 'Brasilia', 'Brussels', 'Dhaka', 'Luanda', 'Algiers', 'Rangoon', 'Caracas', 'Kiev', 'Tashkent', 'Madrid', 'Stockholm', 'Bangkok', 'Lima', 'Dakar', 'Johannesburg', 'Amsterdam', 'Seoul', 'Manila', 'Berlin', 'Kinshasa', 'New Delhi', 'Athens', 'Baghdad', 'Addis Ababa', 'Tehran', 'Buenos Aires', 'Kabul', 'Vienna', 'Taipei', 'Washington, D.C.', 'London', 'Riyadh', 'Cape Town', 'Moscow', 'Mexico City', 'Rome', 'Beijing', 'Nairobi', 'Jakarta', 'Bogota', 'Cairo', 'Tokyo', 'Paris', 'Santiago', 'Singapore']
```

You can use `nybb` instead of `naturalearth_cities`.

```
['Staten Island', 'Queens', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Bronx']
```

Comment: ```
print(cities[cities['name'].str.contains('New')])
  name                   geometry
177  New Delhi  POINT (77.19998 28.60002)
```
I am only interested  in the city name only. Therefore using nybb is not going to work but even i haven't get anything with nybb.

Comment: @CrazyC you need to download a dataset that meets your needs or create your own.

Comment: Do you know any legal and valid link?